# how to make if there is no file it will do nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

hey so I'm trying to const some JSON

```
const cidc = require('./cid/cid.json')
const dc = require('./details/cid.json')
const lc = require('./lik/cid.json')
if(!cidc){          
return
}else{
 fs.unlinkSync('./src/main/setting/cid/cid.json')
} if(!dc) {
return
}else {
    fs.unlinkSync('./src/main/setting/details/cid.json')
} if (!lc){
return
}else {
 fs.unlinkSync('./src/main/setting/lik/cid.json')
}
```

so I'm trying to delete the dc file and it error

how can I make if there is no such file named that it will do nothing (aka return nothing)
and if there is a file named that it will const it to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since require throws an error of `Error: Cannot find module ...` and you don't catch those errors, your script will fail.

You could define a new require-function where you catch the error and return undefined:

```
function safeRequire(path) {
 try {
   return require(path);
 } catch(err) {
   return undefined;
 }
}
```

Then use this function in your script:

```
const cidc = safeRequire('./cid/cid.json')
const dc = safeRequire('./details/cid.json')
const lc = safeRequire('./lik/cid.json')
// rest of your code
```

Also you can simplify your if/else conditions by inverting the condition:

```
if (cidc) {          
  fs.unlinkSync('./src/main/setting/cid/cid.json')
}
if (dc) {
  fs.unlinkSync('./src/main/setting/details/cid.json')
}
if (lc){
  fs.unlinkSync('./src/main/setting/lik/cid.json')
}
```

Alternatively you don't even need to use `require` at all, just check if the files exist using e.g. `fs.access(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use unlink with try catch without any requires

```
function unlink(filePath) {
  try {
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
  } catch (e) {
    //ignore
  }
}
unlink('./src/main/setting/cid/cid.json')
unlink('./src/main/setting/details/cid.json')
unlink('./src/main/setting/lik/cid.json')
```

Comment: but isnt that will error if there is no such a file named something ?

Comment: Yes, the error will be thrown by fs.unlink and caught in the catch block. You can further check the error code ENOENT in the catch block and show message to user.